# Is it possible to run just through the item pipeline without crawling with Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a `.jl` file with items I've scraped. I have another pipeline now which was not present when I was doing the scraping. Is it possible to run just the pipeline, and have it apply the new pipeline without doing the crawl/scrape again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer: Yes.

To bypass the downloader while having other components of scrapy working, you could use a customized downloader middleware which returns `Response` objects in its `process_request` method. Check the details: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html

But in your case I personally think you could use some simple code to download the `.jl` file from your local file system. A quick (and full) example:

```
# coding: utf8

import json
import scrapy


class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'sample_spider'
    start_urls = [
        'file:///tmp/some_file.jl',
    ]
    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'your_pipeline_here': 100,
        },
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for line in response.body.splitlines():
            jdata = json.loads(line)
            yield jdata
```

Just replace `'/tmp/some_file.jl'` with your actual path to the file.

Comment: It seems that the `parse` method is not being called ( I tried to put some print statements inside, as well as adding a `pdb.set_trace`) . I tried running  like: `scrapy crawl pipeline_loader -o new_file.jl`

Comment: @Geo Ah sorry I must have taken too much alcohol tonight.. Scrapy recognizes only the `start_urls` attribute which shall be a list of URLs, while in my answer it was `start_url` of a single URL. Answer updated.